# Android ApplyBatch: cannot rollback - no transaction is active

Tags: android, sqlite, transactions

I override the applybatch(), and execute some insert operations, but sometimes it will report the bug as follows. More important, I cannot reproduce it ...

Thanks in advance.

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException 

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecute 【count : 75】 【user_count : 60/58414】
        android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: cannot rollback - no transaction is active (code 1)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecute(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.execute(SQLiteConnection.java:548)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.endTransactionUnchecked(SQLiteSession.java:439)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.endTransaction(SQLiteSession.java:401)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.endTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:522)
        at com.example.home.launcher.LauncherProvider.applyBatch(LauncherProvider.java:290)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.applyBatch(ContentProvider.java:222)
        at android.content.ContentProviderClient.applyBatch(ContentProviderClient.java:225)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.applyBatch(ContentResolver.java:947)
        at com.example.home.launcher.k.run(LauncherModel.java:221)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

    @Override
    public ContentProviderResult[] applyBatch(ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operations)
            throws OperationApplicationException {
        ContentProviderResult[] result;
        synchronized (mLock) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            db.beginTransaction();
            try {
                result = super.applyBatch(operations);
                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            } finally {
                db.endTransaction();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: sorry, changed it now ;-)

Comment: What does your `apply()` look like?

Comment: I dont override apply(), just use ContentProviderOperation.applly()

Comment: Your aplyBatch method seem to be ok. Could you add an example of the operations performed in the transaction?